# Documentation for using 3rd party intellectual property for Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am in the process of submitting an app to Google Play for review. This app is built for a 3rd party, but will be published by me.

Google Play allows this, but requests documentation showing that I have permission to use this IP.

Does anyone have any clue what kind of documentation I need in order to get this approved so that I can get it from my client?

This is the link to the form that I will be submitting to Google: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6320428

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: "This app is built for a 3rd party, but will be published by me." doesn't matter to google you just don't use .. Brand names and logos, graphic assets, audio, etc on screenshots